# Iterate array elements in <li>

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I have a countries array called

```
$countries_list = array('United Kingdom, Spain, Norway, etc').
```

I want build a list same this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="Norway">Norway</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="Spain">Spain</a>
   </li>

   ETC...
</ul>
```

I'm trying this version, but not works correctly:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($countries_list as $country)       
        <li><a href="$country">{{$country}}</a></li>                
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This report me:

```
<li><a href="Spanish Nordway United Kingdom">Spanish Nordway United Kingdom</a></li>
```

It's Laravel syntax:

```
{{}} = echo.
```

Comment: Any error you getting?

Comment: Are you sure about the array?` var_dump()` the actual variable and see..

Comment: Yes, var_dump report my array: array(1) { [0]=> string(100) "Spain, United Kingdom, etc" }

Comment: @FunnyFrontend please up-vote the answer also. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is all countries are came with comma separation in a single string, so change them like this initially:

```
$countries_list = array('United Kingdom', 'Spain', 'Nordwary', 'etc');
```

And then use:

```
<ul>
  @foreach($countries_list as $country)

    <li><a href="{{$country}}">{{$country}}</a></li>

  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Note:- try to correct your country array format initially,  otherwise no solution will work. If you cannot change array format For that to solve you again need to explode `$countries_list` and iterate with `foreach`. for explode do like this:-

```
$countries_list = explode(', ', 'United Kingdom, Spain, Nordwary, etc');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not an array of countries but an array with one string that contains all countries. Change it so it contains individual strings:

```
$countries_list = array('United Kingdom', 'Spain', 'Nordwary', 'etc');
```

If you get the input dynamically as comma separated string, use `explode()`:

```
$countries_list = explode(', ', 'United Kingdom, Spain, Nordwary, etc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss {{}}.

```
  <ul>
        @foreach($countries_list as $country)

                <li><a href="{{$country}}">{{$country}}</a></li>

        @endforeach
        </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, I missed, but this no fixed anything.